# How to import multiple Images neatly in next/js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, next.js, next-images

The question is that I am having 10 images in my `public` folder and I want to use them in a component. Instead of writing

```
import imgurl1 from "../../public/celsius.gif";
import imgurl2 from "../../public/compass.gif";
import imgurl3 from "../../public/rain.gif";
.
.
.
import imgurl8 from "../../public/thermo.gif";
import imgurl9 from "../../public/sunset.gif";
import imgurl10 from "../../public/wind.gif";
```

the above code, I want to use something more neatly and clean code? Is there any way not to repeat the same line and import all of them?

I am assuming something like

```
import { imgurl1,imgurl2,...imgurl10, } from "../../public";
```

Answer (score 6):

Next JS's importing of images is implemented as a webpack plugin which is implemented using `import symbol from 'filepath` - You won't be able to change the way that works directly, but there is nothing preventing you from creating a helper file that exports the imported files.

In other words, you can take all your imports and move them to `images.js` and export all of them at the bottom.  You then can import them using a destructured import.